# Calculating SQL query processing

Tags: php, mysql

All I want do to is simply get the result of how long (in seconds) the PHP takes to process the SQL query. Am I on a right track? Is my code correct to get the result I want?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test3", $con);

    $start = microtime(TRUE);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test`
    ORDER BY `test`.`test2` DESC
    LIMIT 0,100");


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>test1</th>
<th>test2</th>
<th>test3</th>
<th>test4</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['test1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['test2'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['test3'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['test4'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

$end = microtime(TRUE);

$sqlTime = $end - $start;


mysql_close($con);
echo $sqlTime
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, microtime is designed to be used for this. The PHP documentation mentions this [use case for `microtime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).
2. Consider putting this into a loop and print out the average result: if the measured time is too small, you can't provide a reliable estimation.
3. Concerning the MySQL request: you should [switch to mysqli or PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Thanks, for the connection advice. I will change that, but I am still concerned whether `$end = microtime (TRUE)` is the right place to have? Or should I put it after the sql query?

Comment: It simply depends on what you want to measure: if it's simply MySQL, put it at the end, and if you want to include PHP processing, keep it there.